# Input data to database using rest api (Login)

Tags: php, angular, ionic4

I have an API that is trying to check a if a user is on the database. However, I'm not sure how to post the data from the input to my API to allow a user to login.

HTML Login page

```
  <ion-item class='ion-padding'>
    <ion-label position="floating">Username (Email)</ion-label>
    <ion-input type='text'name="email" #email [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item class='ion-padding'>
    <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type='password'  name="password" #password [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

Login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.page.html',

})
export class HomePage {
  username = '';
  password = '';

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httpH: HttpHeaders,
    public loading: LoadingController) { }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a `button` in HTML and bind `(click)="onSubmit()"`

TS:

```
  onSubmit() {
    let data = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }


    this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data)
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        console.log(resp)
      }, (error) => {
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The clean way would be to create an authentication service and add all authentication related methods to it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<any>('localhost:2800/login', {username, password});
  }
}
```

Use the service and subscribe to the result in your `Login.ts`, and call the method when user click submit/ login. You will get the result, failed or successful, in both case you have to handle it. If fails, show the error to the user, if successful, probably redirecting user to home/ dashboard.

```
this.authService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(res => {
  if (res) {
    // if you are using JWT store the token
  } else {// depends how you handle}
}), error => {
  if (error.status === 401) {
    // Failed to login if you are returning 401
  }
});;
```

Make sure you instantiate the service in the constructor:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService)
```

Comment: How do i go about storing the jwt token?